# Thus far? vs So far?

Tags: phrases, differences, questions

I would like to know what is the difference between "How is your day thus far?" vs. How is your day so far? and if there is any significant difference between the two questions. I always assumed that they essential meant the same thing, but I am uncertain at this very point. Is there any one who would be willing to help me understand the differences between the two. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There is no significant difference between the two. Most dictionaries include a sense for *thus* defining it as a synonym for *so*, but I can't think of any cases where it would be used as such other than in *thus far*, so you shouldn't consider *thus* and *so* interchangeable other than in that one [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase).

Comment: I am feeling better, *so/thus* I shall go to work.

Comment: so/thus you shouldn't consider thus and so interchangeable

Comment: I'm sure he meant "other than in this context", as opposed to in this specific phrase. Either way, I'm glad I was able to scratch this 'thus v so' itch. Thus, I am grateful.